# apply WAL logs to standby server in postgres

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, postgresql

For switchover operation I need to apply WAL logs to standby Server.

Please tell me how to apply WAL Logs to standby server in postgres?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read the postgres documentation on the postgres web site. Amazingly the documentation details how to do this.